# ImageMagick cannot find liblqr even though it's installed

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, imagemagick

I have two separate places where I have installed ImageMagick from source. The first is Linux Mint 18.1 and the second is Ubuntu 16.04. On both of them I have installed `liblqr-1-0-dev` from aptitude in order to use the lqr delegate. I configure both with the following:

```
./configure --with-gslib --with-lqr
```

On Linux Mint this works fine, but on Ubuntu it says it cannot find the lqr library. I've tried the following to ensure liblqr is installed:

lqr is found in ldconfig

```
xxxxx@vps:~/ImageMagick-7.0.6-0$ ldconfig -p | grep lqr
        liblqr-1.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblqr-1.so.0
        liblqr-1.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblqr-1.so
```

Apt says lqr is installed

```
xxxxx@vps:~/ImageMagick-7.0.6-0$ sudo apt install liblqr-1-0-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
liblqr-1-0-dev is already the newest version (0.4.2-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What else can I do to get ImageMagick to realize it's installed?

Comment: Does `pkg-config --cflags lqr-1` return results? If so, you man need to remove `config.cache` and try again.

Comment: @emcconville That did return results that lead to me solving this issue. It turns out that liblqr requires glib-2.0, but aptitude doesn't install it alongside liblqr. I had to install `libglib2.0` before it worked correctly. If you want, you can post an answer and I'll accept it since it seems that was the issue. If you don't want to, I'll just post one detailing what I did.